# wpf. MsChart. Увеличить область построения графика

Tags: wpf, диаграммы

Когда и строю график в **MsChart** (wpf, xaml) верхняя граница области построения графика намного ниже, чем верхняя граница самого **MsChart**. 
Как увеличить область построения ?

Comment: Это место для того, что разместить Title. Но я не могу удалить его

Comment: Я нашел выход из этого положения) 

я программно сбросил стиль титула: 

msChart.TitleStyle = null;

Answer (score 1):

Можно назначить пустой стиль.

```
<charting:Chart.TitleStyle>
    <Style/>
</charting:Chart.TitleStyle>
```